# Solr Suggester taking too long to provide response

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using Solr Suggester to provide suggestion in the search page of our application. But every suggestion request to Solr is taking too long to send response. I have tried with multiple lookup Impl such as AnalyzingLookupFactory, AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory, FuzzyLookupFactory etc.

Below is my configuration:

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
        <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
        <str name="field">spell_suggest</str>
        <str name="weightField">spell_suggest</str>
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
        <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="suggester">
        <str name="name">altSuggester</str>
        <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="field">spell_suggest</str>
        <str name="weightField">spell_suggest</str>
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
 </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
<lst name="defaults">
    <!--<str name="suggest.dictionary">mySuggester</str> -->
    <str name="suggest.dictionary">altSuggester</str>
    <str name="suggest">true</str>
    <str name="suggest.count">6</str>
    <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
</lst>
<arr name="components">
    <str>suggest</str>
</arr>
</requestHandler>
```

The response, with just 42000 indexed documents, is taking close to 5 to 7 seconds to provide response. This is impacting the functionality badly in the application

Following is my request: `http://<myIP>:8983/solr/mycollection/suggest?df=spell_suggest&suggest=true&suggest.build=true&q=Vendor`

Please suggest if I need to provide few more configurations or need to modify existing configurations to improve performance.

Thanks!

Comment: When you're issuing `suggest.build` each time, you're effectively asking for the suggestion index to be _rebuilt from scratch_ each time you're querying the suggester. It should only be rebuilt after changes if necessary (depending on which `dictionaryImpl` you're using).

Comment: Many many thanks @MatsLindh. Indeed suggest.build=true was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're issuing suggest.build each time, you're effectively asking for the suggestion index to be rebuilt from scratch each time you're querying the suggester.

It should only be rebuilt after changes if necessary (depending on which `dictionaryImpl` you're using).